# mysql questões randômicas

Tags: mysql, query

Tenho uma dúvida um tanto quanto complexa e preciso de ajuda:

Possuo um banco de dados com as seguintes ligações:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Exemplificando:** Estou na aula de história sobre Karl Marx. Esta aula é linkada  a um determinado grupo de "assunto" de Karl Marx que possui um banco de 100 questões. Porém, dessas 100, eu já respondi 50 ("questoes_control").

**O objetivo do problema é:** Gerar apenas 5 questões randômicas de acordo com a aula selecionada e que eu ainda não tenha respondido (cada questão possui 5 respostas).

cheguei na query:

```
SELECT aulas.nomeaula, 
       assuntos.nomeassunto, 
       questoes.questao, 
       respostas.resposta 
FROM aulas 
INNER JOIN aulas_has_assuntos ON (aulas.idaulas = aulas_has_assuntos.aulas_idaulas) 
INNER JOIN assuntos ON (aulas_has_assuntos.assuntos_idassuntos = assuntos.idassuntos) 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM assuntos_has_questoes WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM questao_control WHERE assuntos_has_questoes.questoes_idquestoes = questao_control.questoes_idquestoes AND questao_control.usuarios_idusuarios=1) ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5) a ON (aulas_has_assuntos.assuntos_idassuntos = a.assuntos_idassuntos) 
LEFT JOIN questoes ON (a.questoes_idquestoes = questoes.idquestoes) 
LEFT JOIN respostas ON (questoes.idquestoes = respostas.questoes_idquestoes)
WHERE aulas.idaulas=2070
```

Alguma ideia?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma forma de fazer (não aconselhável em tabelas com muitos registros): use o `rand()` e `LIMIT`:

```
SELECT aulas.nomeaula, 
       assuntos.nomeassunto, 
       questoes.questao, 
       respostas.resposta 
FROM aulas 
INNER JOIN aulas_has_assuntos ON (aulas.idaulas = aulas_has_assuntos.aulas_idaulas) 
INNER JOIN assuntos ON (aulas_has_assuntos.assuntos_idassuntos = assuntos.idassuntos) 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM assuntos_has_questoes WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM questao_control WHERE assuntos_has_questoes.questoes_idquestoes = questao_control.questoes_idquestoes AND questao_control.usuarios_idusuarios=1) ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5) a ON (aulas_has_assuntos.assuntos_idassuntos = a.assuntos_idassuntos) 
LEFT JOIN questoes ON (a.questoes_idquestoes = questoes.idquestoes) 
LEFT JOIN respostas ON (questoes.idquestoes = respostas.questoes_idquestoes)
WHERE aulas.idaulas=2070
ORDER BY rand() 
LIMIT 5
```

Você está limitando sua busca em 5 registros (`LIMIT 5`) e ordenando a busca randomicamente (`rand()`).

---

Exemplo de query randômica, com performance:

```
SET @r := (SELECT FLOOR(RAND() * (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mytable)));
SET @sql := CONCAT('SELECT * FROM mytable LIMIT 1 OFFSET ', @r);
PREPARE stmt1 FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt1;
```

Você seta a variável `r`, faz um sorteio usando a quantidade de registros da tabela puxada por `COUNT(*)`.

Concatena o `select` com o número sorteado, e executa a query.

[Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6541644/selecting-random-rows-with-mysql/6542113#6542113)

[+ Link](http://jan.kneschke.de/projects/mysql/order-by-rand/)